# Smart-table : Disable column sorting

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat, smart-table

Below static example has sort on first name, but disabled sort on email column:

```
<tr>
    <th st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
    <th>email</th>
</tr>
```

But, my columns are dynamic. So I am creating dynamic column headers in an `ng-repeat`. Wether columns should be sortable or not is decided by an `isSortable` flag.

```
     <tr>
        <th st-sort="column.isSortable" ng-repeat="column in columns">{{column.columnName}}</th>
    </tr>
```

How do I make only the colums with `isSortable` set as `true` sortable?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you set your st-sort on an inner element

```
   <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="column in columns"><span st-sort="column.sortProperty" ng-if="column.isSortable">{{column.columnName}}</span><span ng-if="!column.isSortable">{{column.columnName}}</span></th></tr>
```

and if you don't want to repeat yourself, you can embed this logic within a directive

Comment: It is not a good salutation. What if my html grow inside th element?